# On surjectivity of the first two coefficients in Fourier transform of functions in dimesnion two

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, fourier-series

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open set and $G(x,\theta): \Omega \times [0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive continuous function. Assume $F:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as

$$F(x)= \int_0^{2\pi}G(x,\theta) (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) d\theta, $$
is surjective. Does there exists a continuous positive function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}g(t)=\infty$ such that

$$H(x)= \int_0^{2\pi}g(G(x,\theta)) (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) d\theta  $$

is not surjective?

Comment: consider review the tittle... I got the feeling you want to say "surjectivity" were now says "subjectivity"

Comment: @Joako Done. Thank you.